Find positions of unique elements in a nested list
I have a nested list with depth 6. The items in the list are mathematical expressions. I want to find the positions of the unique items in the nested list. I have found the following, which works for a non-nested list:
positionDuplicates[list_] := GatherBy[Range@Length[list], list[[#]] &]

Ideally, the function would also count how many times the item is repeated in the nested list.

Do you know the function "Position"?

myList = {....};

myCounts = Counts[Flatten[myList]];

hh = (myList /. myCounts);

Position[hh, 1]

Test this with
myList = Table[RandomInteger[{1, 20}], {3}, {4}, {2}, {6}, {5}]


Thank you, but since the entries of the nested list are expressions, they need to be tested for equality using FullSimplify[expr1-expr2]==0
